# x3dom -> inline URL format in a Blazor Server App issues

Tags: blazor, x3dom

I am able to load an external .x3d file using a html file but I can't seem to get this working in a Blazor Server App in the _Host.cshtml file.
I have the x3d file in a models folder under wwroot and my html looks like:

```
<inline url='/models/Deer.x3d'>  </inline>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the step of adding a mime type for the x3d file extension.